# Which version is most suitable for me

Tags: hardware

I have a computer with the following spec:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM COU @ 2.20 GHZ
Ram 8 GB
x64

I also have a SSD disk running on my Dell Vostro, does that need something extra?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) The SSD on your Dell Vostro will be detected automatically and TRIM will be enabled automatically for Intel and Samsing SSDs, otherwise you have to enable TRIM manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should get Ubuntu 14.04.1. It comes with 5 years support, how cool is that? :D
http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/

"64-bit PC (AMD64) 
Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead. "

Download it here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download

SSD: If your disk or usb boot don't boot up properly, you may change your Bios Settings (Usually F2 at startup). BIOS and UEFI: **set it to AHCI** If you can't see the AHCI option, then you should just boot it up and should work just fine.